# Intuition of weak solutions of elliptic equations in divergence form

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, intuition, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a domain, and consider the following equation

(1) $-D_{j}(a_{ij}D_{i}u) = 0$ (Einstein notation)

The function $u \in H^{1}(\Omega)$ is a weak solution of (1) if

$\int\limits_{\Omega} a_{ij}D_{i}uD_{j}\varphi =0$ for any $\varphi \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$.

for $a_{ij} \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

What is the importance of finding weak solutions? Why Because these solutions live exactly in Sobolev spaces?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/317080/8157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original problem you need two derivatives of $u$, whereas for the weak formulation one suffices. So you have reduced the regularity required for $u$ by integrating by parts. Sobolev spaces have been created specifically to be the appropriate spaces where solutions of PDEs in work form live.